# Excel - Different sorting when printing worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using Microsoft Excel 2010, I have a worksheet that includes a table with ~200 rows, and every cell in the A column contains different text values. When editing the worksheet, the rows aren't sorted. I'd like to be able to have the worksheet automatically sort the rows alphabetically when printed.

While editing:

```
abc | 123 | more text
zqg | 794 | other
bbg | 384 | more details
gqq | 734 | input
```

Printed worksheet:

```
abc | 123 | more text
bbg | 384 | more details
gqq | 734 | input
zqg | 794 | other
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean to say - you want to sort the data and print it when you push the print button. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but the data should remain unsorted after printing.